# Spring MVC + Spring Security + JPA returns Null ModelAndView and won't authenticate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

as above I have a webapp in spring MVC in which the following *ARE* working:

- a 'toy' version of the authentication in a dummy page with no js/img/css/png assets
- URL mapping in the controller. So: `http://myhost/myapp/login` and `http://myhost/myapp/homepage/*` all serve up a page
- Hibernate/JPA integration
- in short, everything EXCEPT that, in the full-fat login page with assets, even when I put in the correct username/pass combination, the authentication is rejected & redirects to the authentication failure URL.

(Spring 3.2, Spring Security 3.1.3. I am using XML-based authentication for now - see below - so nothing to do with the Hibernate/JPA piece, I think it's exclusively an issue with how I've set up Spring)

My questions, then are two:

- is the .png file triggering an authentication call as it's being processed by the servlet? In which case, how do I filter it out? (.jpg .js .css is ignored by default as 'Public Object' and so not security-screened?
- Is there something odd with the configuration files (reproduced below) now security has been bolted on?

I suspect the following lines from the server log are relevant:

**debug.log**

```
09:29:52,516 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:999 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
09:29:52,517 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:946 - Successfully completed request
09:29:52,517 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:115 - Chain processed normally
09:29:52,517 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:269 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
09:29:52,517 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
09:29:52,983 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
09:29:52,983 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:139 - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
09:29:52,983 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:85 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@104ce68. A new one will be created.
09:29:52,983 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
09:29:52,984 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
09:29:52,984 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
09:29:52,984 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
09:29:52,984 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
09:29:52,984 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
09:29:52,985 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:102 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 2AE4A610A87DADA1FC2D3EC33BAC5176; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'

09:29:52,990 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:999 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
09:29:52,991 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:946 - Successfully completed request
09:29:52,991 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:115 - Chain processed normally
09:29:52,991 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:269 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
09:29:52,991 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

At the moment I am using simple, XML-based authentication as follows:

**security-context.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/homepage*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <!-- custom securiy URL mappings -->
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/homepage/main"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />     
</http>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
    <user name="user" password="pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Other relevant config files:

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.blah.controller" />
<!-- URI mapping for static content -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="viewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
</bean>

 <!-- also add the following beans to get rid of some exceptions -->
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="yourpackagename.yourwebproject" version="2.5">
<display-name>my web project</display-name>

<!-- Spring Framework Configuration -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>       
        classpath:application-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
      org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<!-- Servlet Configurations -->
<!-- Web App Dispatcher -->
<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Mentioning the Context Loader Listener class of Spring Framework as a listener -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Filter Configurations -->
<!-- UTF-8 encoding filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- logging -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

Comment: What are the names of input fields? Are they `j_username` and `j_password`?

Comment: Yes they are - all default stuff. Have added the HTML for reference.

Comment: Jeez, what a numpty. Password field name/id was still set as input_password from UI designer, I hadn't switched it. @n1ckolas - thank you for your lateral thinking!

Comment: @tactcAl I always tell to my team: devil is in the details :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the spring filter is applied to all requests, this is also the case for png images. For the first question you can filter png's with a line like this

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**/*.png" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
```

or if you decide to use access expressions with

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**/*.png" access="true" />
```

But from your config files, this should be the case anyway.

Another way of doing this is:

```
<http pattern="/**/*.png" security="none"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Adrian is good.
With Spring 4 and Spring Security 4 we do filtering for images and others resources like that now:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/assets**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/images**" access="permitAll" />
...
</http>
```

That ant-style pattern notation allows you to do not care about folders hierarchies for your resources.

Of course you must use appropriate access rights with tags like that:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/private.do" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/admin.do" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

And do not forget to activate CSRF protection with:

```
<csrf/>
```

I found it very handy to configure. Five years ago it was not so easy :)